# How do I access the values of a Form.control?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I am trying to access the values that are corresponding the options of a select menu in a React bootstrap form.

Here is my code

```
handleChange(e) {
            var options = e.target.options;
            var selectedValues = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
              if (options[i].selected) {
                selectedValues.push(options[i].value);
              }
            }
            console.log(selectedValues);
          }
<Form.Group controlId="Location">
    <Form.Control as="select" multiple onChange={this.handleChange}>
        <option value="1132348">New York City</option>
        <option value="1154532">Boston</option>
        <option value="1147401">San Francisco</option>
        <option value="1146821">Los Angeles</option>
        <option value="1150505">Seattle</option>
        <option value="1151614">Portland</option>
    </Form.Control>
</Form.Group>
```

For example, if I selected the "New York City" option, how would I get access the number "1132348" for use.

Comment: Why these particular values?

Answer (score 0):

as you are using select with multiple selection so please try this handleChange even:

```
handleChange: function(e) {
  var options = e.target.options;
  var selectedValues = [];
  for (var i = 0, i < options.length; i++) {
    if (options[i].selected) {
      selectedValues.push(options[i].value);
    }
  }
  console.log(selectedValues);
}
```

Comment: what do I pass to this function and what do I put in the 'onClick' section of the button I have

Comment: you can use <Form.Control as="select" multiple onChange={this.handleChange}>

Comment: @je1013 : we will be passing the event object to the listener function.

Comment: Ok, now it is saying "Cannot read property 'handleChange' of undefined" I'm confused because I do have the values of each option set to something

Comment: cna you please update your question with full example?

Comment: no no... it is not completed code. I want to see your complete code string from import to end.

Comment: it seems its a little too long to send, but I can assure you this is the only section of code that affects this part

Comment: I dont get anything wrong in this code. by the way, are you using functional component or  class component?